# Python: How to include table prefix in mysql result header

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy, pymysql

I need to execute the following SQL query in python.

```
SELECT table_a.company, table_b.company
FROM table_a
LEFT JOIN table_b ON table_a.id = table_b.id
```

but the problem, when I run my code (tried using `pymysql` (cursor.execute) and `pandas` (pd.read_sql)), they showed

```
| company        | company        |
-----------------------------------
| <some company> | <some company> |
```

Whereas, my expectation, the output should be like this:

```
| table_a.company        | table_b.company        |
---------------------------------------------------
| <some company>         | <some company>         |
```

(the header contains **table prefix**)

How do I achieve this?

My conditions:

- I am avoiding using alias, since the real query contain wildcard `table_a.*`
- I want to try `mysql.connector`, but I heard you need to be in python 64-bit. 

  In my case, I need to stay on python 32-bit, So I can't use it.

Below are my codes:

1. Pandas

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connection_string)
df = pd.read_sql(text(query), engine, chunksize=chunksize):
print(df)
```

2. Pymysql

```
engine = pymysql.connect(host=host, user=user, password=passw, port=port, db=database)
cursor = engine.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
result = cursor.fetchmany(chunksize)
num_fields = len(cursor.description)
field_names = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=field_names, data=result)
print(df)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: how about `SELECT table_a.company as "table_a.company",...`?

Comment: I am avoiding using alias, because I need to use wildcard sometimes, like `table_a.*`
I have updated the questions. Thanks for the reply